# Android studio execution error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

and my app level gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demo.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'

  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After using `multiDexEnabled true` still I got error as

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/SortedList.class

Also I have cleaned and rebuild the project still error not fixed!!

Comment: did you import any third part libraries or modules?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
defaultConfig {
  multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

in your dependencies.